# Install Xamarin on Visual Studio 2015 with Xamarin on Visual Studio 2013 already installed

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, installation

I have Xamarin installed on the Visual Studio 2013 on Windows Operating System. It works fine.

There is Xamarin tools in VS2013 as follows:

[image]

My problem is as follows:

I have recently installed Visual Studio 2015 on my desktop on Windows operating system. I thought when I opened the VS2015, I expected to see the `Xamarin` in it, but it does not. Then I installed the `Xamarin` again, and again and again, but still `Xamarin` does not show up in VS2015.

I wonder what is wrong? What am I missing?
By the way, I still have VS2013 on my desktop.

No Xamarin tools in VS 2015 as follows:

[image]

I even tried the following approach, still no luck.

> Control Panel -> Programs -> Programs and Features Choose Xamarin
>
> Click Change -> Next -> Click the desired drop down for each items in the tree view and select "Will be installed on local hard drive."
>
> Click Next

[image]

I am even getting the following screen when installation is completed, but still I could not able to see Xamarin in VS2015.

[image]

Comment: Did you check at Visual Studio plugins? Xamarin should be installed there, if not try to instal it from the plugin window.

Comment: I have attempted to that as well, no luck. see my update.

Comment: Sorry my company block images. What I meant is in Visual Studio => Tools => Extensions and Updates => Online => Search and install the Xamarin package. Did you do that?.

Comment: Yes I have done it as well, no luck.

Comment: Resign yourself to the fact that you're going to need to reinstall Visual Studio a few times before this works, in my experience.  It's painful.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I have installed Xamarin in my Visual Studio 2015 two days ago and it showing Xamarin under **Tools**. Below I have described the approach which I have followed to install Xamarin in Visual Studio 2015.

> Go to ***Contol Panel*** >> ***Program Features*** >> ***Visual Studio
> 2015*** >> ***Change***>> ***Modify***
>
> **1.** Select C#/.Net(Xamarin) under Cross Platform Mobile Development

[image]

> **2.** Check if these three red marked items are checked or not.

[image]

> **3.** And then press update.It will download all the required packages to run Xamarin on VS 2015.Hope it helps you!!

Comment: This fixed my issue - the universal Xamarin installer failed and said I had to go through the manual process. The thing that screwed me up at first is that since I had Android Studio and SDK setup already, I thought I could use that SDK. This is not possible - Xamarin requires specific versions of the SDK and SDK tools, and won't work with the latest versions. The visual studio installer eventually got everything it needed. MS and Xamarin really need to sort this out - the Xamarin installer is pretty useless in my opinion, unless you are doing a fully clean install (VS + Xamarin on a new PC).

Comment: Did the job for me. I had a fresh VS2015 installation, but when I created an Android project it redirected me to the Xamarin web site. There it gave me an installer that wanted to install VS Community edition which was not an option for me

Comment: @TadijaBagarić Good to hear that. Enjoy coding. :)

Comment: am not getting seen 3rd item i.e Java SE Development kit (7.0.550.13) in feautures, i have VS2015 enterprise edition

Comment: This solution worked well. In my opinion this should be the correct answer. You don't need to remove other VS versions.

Answer (score 17):

I recently had horrendous problems trying to install Xamarin on VS2015 + Win10.  (I don't have any other VS versions installed.)  Even a full install and reinstall left huge holes in the installation.  I tried repeatedly and each time the whole dev environment seemed to get itself in a different unusable state.

The fix for me, which is probably hitting a nut with a sledgehammer, was to:

1. Uninstall Xamarin (via Control Panel|Uninstall).
2. Uninstall Visual Studio (via Control Panel|Uninstall).
3. Follow Xamarin's manual uninstallation procedures [Full Xamarin Uninstall](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/installation/uninstalling_xamarin/).
4. Perform full reinstall of Visual Studio, being sure to tick the boxes shown in the answer by Parth Patel above.

This resulted in a faultless, fully functioning Xamarin environment for me.  Overkill, maybe, but worth a go if all else fails.

Answer (score 9):

**Here is the solution:**

I have deleted all the existing versions of visual studio ( 2010, 2012, 2013) except Visual Studio 2015 and then installed the Xamarin, and then I could able to see Xamarin on Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: This is not solving the case of having both vs2013 and vs2015 installed with xamarin or at least vs2015 with xamarin without the need of uninstalling vs2013.

Answer (score 4):

It is not required to delete previous versions of VS. I have Xamarin Studio, VS 2013 and now VS 2015 and working perfectly. I moved to VS 2015 due to recent purchase of Xamarin by MS and that VS 2015 has Xamarin included.

I believe the issue with this question is was that your VS 2015 install did not include the add ins as pointed out in another answer in this question.

After the VS 2015 install -the only caveat was projects created initially in Xaramin Studio and then Opened in VS 2015 to needed to have the build configuration in the project tweaked. If not you could not get the project to build and then be deployed to an emulator or device for debug testing.

Answer (score 3):

We have a few troubleshooting steps on our Knowledge Base that you can find here:

https://kb.xamarin.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1643349-missing-visual-studio-extensions-after-installation

**Note:** Some of these steps have older versions listed in the respective paths. You should use the latest version number available.

Answer (score 3):

I had some problems with my emulator best way to fix the problems is to uninstall everything (emulators, android sdk, vs, xamarin) and reinstall it.

It is also important to delete other or older versions of visual studio. Then you should probably see you options.

Answer (score 3):

Before any install or uninstall actions. Try open some sample Xamarin project, in most cases during opening project in VS 15, it will show you, what needs to be installed or what is missing / corrupted.

[Xamarin samples](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples-all/)

Answer (score 2):

First try to uninstall all the other versions of Visual Studio (VS) 2013 in this case.  Then try to reinstall Xamarin.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2015 is little bit different from 2013 version, I am also using xamarin on visual studio 2015. But that is not listed under tools menu like 2013.

Maybe developers had changed that, you can go to "start a new project"(just like you start new app development), there you can find xamarin/android projects list, there you can start new android projects.

Answer (score -3):

This is strange, I did not have any problem with Xamarin & VS 2015 (community).

You said,

> I will see the Xamarin in it

Did you try to create a project or/and add your account in the new VS Installation ?

Comment: Yes, I have also tried to create a project, but still I see a link to download xamarin. I do not see any xamarin tools in vs 2015.

Comment: Ok, Which version of Windows are you using ( Windows 10 ? )

Comment: Windows 7 enterprise.

Comment: This shouldn't be an answer but a comment instead.

Comment: +1 sorry it's a reflex. That strange, I know that the last version of Xamarin have seme compatibilty problem with the latest update of Windows 10 but I don't know if Windows 7 have the same issue... sorry