# Xamarin won't install in current of Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, installation

I have tried uninstalling Xamarin, and reinstalling Visual Studio 2015, and it keeps failing.

#### this below

[image]

#### results in this

[image]

Is there anywhere I can grab that missing package directly.  I have the Visual Studio installer downloading the packages from the internet.  If I can install that package manually (aka, an MSI), then I believe it should be ok.  Xamarin (as part of Visual Studio) won't install until this ancient SDK installs.

I also tried Xamarins' installer, but it never shows up in Visual Studio 2015, likely because of this dependency failing.

Some other things I have tried :

- [Common issues in Visual Studio 2015 setup](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3039361)
- [StackOverflow: Install Xamarin on Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36158015/install-xamarin-on-visual-studio-2015)
- [Xamarin: Installing Xamarin on Windows](https://developer.xamarin.com/videos/?v=Installing_Xamarin_on_Windows)
- [Uninstalling Xamarin](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/installation/uninstalling_xamarin/)

Comment: You may get them here: [Google API Level 19](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/x86/google_apis_x86-19_r02.zip) and [Google API Level 21](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-21_r01.zip)

Comment: ty, you wouldn't happen to know where to unzip them to ... or even better, how to force visual studio to install from those files ?

Comment: Try something like... `C:\..\android-sdks\system-images\android-19\x86\"Extract that here"` and `C:\..\android-sdks\system-images\android-21\x86\"Extract that here"` Not sure though.

Comment: You should be able to go to Tools > Android > Android SDK Manager and install them from there.

Comment: I tried the installer a couple more times, and it is still failing, however `Tools > Android`, `Tools > iOS`,  and `Tools > Xamarin Account...` are now finally showing up.  `Tools > iOS > ***` is all greyed out tho, making it impossible to follow the instructions in Xamarin's video to connect to my mac, but at least I am much closer now.

Comment: You'll need to be connected to your Mac with Xamarin.iOS installed for the iOS menu to be enabled.

Answer (score 0):

try to open the SDK Manger from your PC ( as an administrator ) and install the missing packages

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually android sdk is failing to download, maybe because of slow or unstable internet connection or the download path which xamarin is using is available anymore.

Go to- http://www.xamarin.com/download and get a separate xamarin installer for your visual studio and install from it.

If it again don't fails to install android sdk then go to https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html and download sdk separately, remember the sdk's install path, you can configure visual studio later.