# Visual Studio 2015 is unable to create a new Xamarin.Forms solution

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

After running into various stability problems with Xamarin in Visual Studio, I was recently forced to reinstall both Windows 10 and Visual Studio. In other words, my newly installed development environment is 100% clean and includes the latest updates to Windows 10 and the complete installation of Visual Studio 2015 Update 3. It also has the latest version of Xamarin for Visual Studio.

I was expecting that this would solve all my Xamarin problems, but it didn't.

Now, when I attempt to create a new Xamarin.Forms solution (Shared or PCL) it encounters this problem creating the Android project ...

[image: PowerShell execution policy setting is set to AllSigned]

... and this error creating all the other projects:

[image: Tasks.dll is being used by another process]

if I then try opening Package Manage Console, it fails to initialize with the following error:

```
The type initializer for 'System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.InitialSessionState' threw an exception.
```

Closing and re-opening Visual Studio allows Package Manage Console to initialize correctly, but then re-trying to create a Xamarin.Forms solution results in Visual Studio crashing while attempting to create the Android project:

[image]

Whilst I have never been impressed with the stability of Xamarin tooling, this is beyond a joke. I've already wasted 2 full days getting back to a completely clean Visual Studio environment and it still doesn't work.

Any ideas what I can do next? Thanks, in advance.

Comment: Have you tried repairing your installation ? Including all the SDK and stuff...

Comment: @Tim Coulter Follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36158015/install-xamarin-on-visual-studio-2015/36283888#36283888

Comment: @Parth Patel: thank you - I guess this what I will have to try. However, I don't hold out much hope, as it is essentially what I have already done by starting with a clean Windows 10 install. The installation of Visual Studio is soooo time consuming that I really want to be sure before I do it again. Worse than that, it consumes tens of gigabytes of download, so my ISP has now rate-limited me for exceeding my monthly "reasonable usage" quota. It would be nice if I could download the bits before starting this exercise for the nth time.

Comment: Have not run into that specific flock of problems but you might try running the following in **Package Manager Console** `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser` and then restart your computer.

Comment: @TimCoulter Another option  would go for manual installation.Set-by-step description is provided under this link https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/windows/manual_installation/

Comment: @hvaughan3 That seemed like a promising idea and, after the reboot, Package Manager Console correctly reported execution policy as Unrestricted. Unfortunately, it didn't affect the behavior of VS - it still crashes during initializing the Android project.

Comment: @Parth Patel: Yes, thanks, I guess I'll have to try that now. I'll post again here if it helps.

Comment: Update: Although my Xamarin installation was already at the latest stable version, I switched to the Beta channel and installed the latest Beta version, which has apparently fixed the problem. I don't believe this was due to a bug in the previously installed version, Instead it may be that the old installation was corrupt, and installing any other version has fixed that corruption.

Comment: Good to see you figured it out and thanks for reporting back the fix!